# json string deserialization to custom object

Tags: c#, json

I am posting this question after reading the posts available. I have an ASP.NET web api controller with following methods.

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomPerson
{
    [DataMember]
    public ulong LongId { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee : CustomPerson
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public class CustomController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddEmployee")]
    public bool AddEmployee(Employee empInfo)
    {
        bool bIsSuccess = false;

        // Code loginc here
        bIsSuccess = true;

        return bIsSuccess;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("AddEmployeeCustom")]
    public async Task<bool> AddEmployeeCustom()
    {
        string rawRequest = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        bool bIsSuccess = false;

        // Code loginc here

        try
        {
            Employee emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(rawRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

        return bIsSuccess;
    }
}
```

When I call the following request to AddEmployee via soap ui the custom object is received without error i.e the empty value for LongId is ignored

```
{
    "Name": "test1",
    "Address": "Street 1",
    "LongId": ""
}
```

When I call the AddEmployeeCustom method the runtime throws exception:

```
Error converting value "" to type 'System.UInt64'. Path 'LongId', line 4, position 14.
```

One option I read is to convert the incoming string to JObject and then create object of Employee class but I am trying to understand and mimic the behavior of default request handling mechanism when the incoming request is automatically handled by the controller and deserialized to Employee object

Comment: change your `LongId` to a `ulong?`

Comment: `LongId` is expecting a number rather than an empty string

Comment: What `long` value should correspond to `"LongId": ""` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON is not valid for your model.

In the first method AddEmployee the process called Model Binding happens. MVC does the job of converting post content into the object. It seems its tolerant to type mismatch and forgives you the empty string.

In the second case, you try to do it yourself, and try simply run deserialization without validating input data. Newtonsoft JSON does not understand empty string and crashes.

If you still need to accept invalid JSON you may want to overwrite default deserialization process by implementing custom converter

```
public class NumberConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ulong) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = reader.Value.ToString();

        ulong result;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || !ulong.TryParse(value, out result))
        {
            return default(ulong);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then specify your custom converter instance when calling deserialize

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(doc.ToJson(), new NumberConverter());
```